# Encryption and Decryption in Mule 4

Tags: mule4

I have got two application where one application receives the xml request and encrypt the field password and send the xml request to another application.

Another application receives the xml request and decrypt the field password using the same key.Is it possible to achieve it in Mule 4 without using java component. My request looks like below:

```
<test>
    <username>camel</username>
    <password>abcdef</password>
</test>
```

I think we could do this using this module (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-crypto).I could see the examples for encrypting not for decrypting. It would be great if someone can help me with this request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions provided by the dw-crypto module are for creating digital secure hashes, not for encryption/decryption. Secure hashes are expected to be very difficult to reverse, and of course they are not useful to decrypt at all.

What you need is the Mule 4 [Cryptography Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/cryptography). There are examples of encrypting/decrypting in the documentation.

Comment: I want the encryption to be added in Mule 3 application and decryption to be done in Mule 4. What is the equivalent in Mule 3

Comment: The Mule 3 equivalent is the Encryption processor: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-message-encryption-processor